# When moving rectangle with background image, the image repeats itself, instead of redrawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a game where the main object, Hero, moves across the map and kills the enemies.

That object is represented as a rectangle with background image.

I've found several solutions for importing the image right, but none of them seems to be fine, all of them are just repeating the image inside of the rectangle.
To be more precise, there is some "hidden" repeated images, and when i move the rectangle, it just unveils them.

```
   Image image = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Untitled);
   TextureBrush tBrush = new TextureBrush(image);
   g.FillRectangle(tBrush, X, Y, characterWidth, characterHeight);
```

When i draw just a rectangle, and use `Move` function, everything is fine,
every time i move, he is redrawing itself. But when i import background image, everything goes messy.

Implementation of `Move` function:

```
public void Move(int width, int height, String direction, List<Obstacles.Rectangle> rectangles)
        {
            int oldX = this.X;
            int oldY = this.Y;
            if (direction == "UP")
            {
                this.Y -= 10;
                if (IsCollided(rectangles) || this.Y < 0)
                {
                    this.Y = oldY;
                }
            }
            if (direction == "DOWN")
            {
                this.Y += 10;
                if (IsCollided(rectangles) || this.Y > height)
                {
                    this.Y = oldY;
                }
            }
            if (direction == "LEFT")
            {
                this.X -= 10;
                if (IsCollided(rectangles) || this.X < 0)
                {
                    this.X = oldX;
                }
            }
            if (direction == "RIGHT")
            {
                this.X += 10;
                if (IsCollided(rectangles) || this.X > width)
                {
                    this.X = oldX;
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: Is this inside Unity?

Comment: Forgot to mention, Windows Forms.

Comment: Can you share `Move function` too?

Comment: @SᴇM `Move` is just increasing/decreasing the X/Y coordinates, nothing special.

Comment: I understand that I just want to see how you have implemented that.

Comment: @SᴇM whenever i press some of the arrow keys, the function `Move` is called with the given direction, after  checking the collisions with obstacles, and dimensions of the map, the coordinates are changed/ or not.

Comment: Using `DrawImageUnscaled` solved the problem, instead of `FillRectangle`.

Comment: The TextureBrush needs to be relocated along with the shape it's used on. Use a Matrix transformation: `using (Matrix m = new Matrix(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, rect.X, rect.Y)) tBrush.Transform = m; // draw the shape g.FillRectangle(tBrush, rect); }`. Comes in handy if you have more shapes to draw.

Comment: @Jimi I've tried that, the problem was same, I've found the solution, `DrawImageUnscaled`.

Comment: Probably because you haven't used `WrapMode.Clamp` in the TextureBrush constructor. `DrawImageUnscaled` has its drawbacks. But, of course, if you're happy with it, it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Forms you need to take care of invalidating and repainting the control. Also if the surface flickers from time to time using double buffering can prevent it.

Invalidate:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=netframework-4.8

OnPaint:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I know about Invalidate, i said before, when i am not filling the shape with Background image, just an ordinary rectangle, everything is fine, and smooth.
Also i am using double buffering.

Comment: From where do you run the code which draws the image (what method/event and what container)? It should be from the OnPaint method of a container (the control that serves as a canvas).

Comment: I found the solution, I used `DrawImageUnscaled` instead of `FillRectangle`. 

As i mentioned before, when I didn't use background image it was fine, that implies calling the method from `OnPaint`.